# Añadir contenido a label por medio de CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente `input`:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="first_name">First name</label>
   <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="first name" required />
</div>
```

Me gustaría, por CSS, añadir un * en el `label` de este y de todos los `input` que sean `required`

Por lo pronto algo parecido a esto:

```
input:required ~ label::before{
  content: "*";
}
```

Y ya si es rojo, seria genial:

```
input:required ~ label::before{
  content: "<i>*<i>";
}
input:required ~ label > i {
  color:red
}
```

Pero que por supuesto, esto no funciona.

Comment: si no puedes modificar el formulario en sí tendrás que hacerlo por javascript, no existen _parent_ selectors en css

Answer (score 2):

Lo más cercano que podrías hacer sin modificar HTML y por CSS es algo así:

```css
input[required] {
  background-image: radial-gradient(red 15%, transparent 16%);
  background-size: 1em 1em;
  background-position: top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="first_name">First name</label>
   <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="first name" required />
</div>
```

Comment: pero esto no se pondría en el label, claro

Comment: Y seria posible de hacer un `::after`?  ya que quiero hacerlo tambia a selects, radios, checkboxes.... un poco generico

Comment: los pseudo-elementos ::before / ::after solo se pueden usar en contenedores y hay algunos elementos en los que no se puede poner, como input, select...

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes, para todas las etiquetas que contengan la clase required.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[required='required']").closest('div').find('label').addClass('required')
})
```

```css
.required:after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Título de la web</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="first_name">First name</label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="first name" required="required" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: El problema de esto es que tengo que poner `class="required"` a los labels, y la verdad no me interesaba. Ya que son 8 paginas con 10 inputs. Solo de pensar que tengo que buscarlos, me cansa

Comment: Ahí lo tienes, mediante jquery, y el atributo required lo tienes que añadir correctamente required="required". Y como veo que te cansa mucho, con que hagas un buscar y remplazar de required -> required="required" y ya esta.

Answer (score 1):

Como te han comentado, no existen selectores "ascendentes" en css, pero (si no puedes añadir clases al label por alguna razón) puedes usar un truco invirtiendo el orden de required y label en el html y corrigiendolo con css y flex (podrias hacerlo incluso con float sin flex).

```css
input:required ~ label::before{
  content: "* ";
  color:red;
}
.form-group{
  display:flex;
}
label{
order:-1;
margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="first name" required />
   <label for="first_name">First name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: EL tema esta en que tengo que buscar todos los required y cambiarlos, sinceramente solo de pensarlo me da un patatús, por que son bastantes en muchas paginas. Entonces lo suyo era crear con CSS ya que comparten el mismo archivo y seria fácil

Comment: Entonces me temo que si lo quieres hacer dinámicamente sin trabajo manual solo podrás hacerlo con un js que añada una clase a todo label que esté antes de un required.
O pegarte el curro de localizar todos los required y hacer algo asi:
`label[for=email]:before, 
label[for=first_name]:before, 
label[for=direction]:before
{`

Answer (score 0):

Con esto debe ser suficiente:

```
label.required:after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: seria útil que expliques tu respuesta.